# Translations tabs of Django parler not showing in the view

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-parler

I'm using django parler to translate my models. now i'm creating a custom admin Panel and i have a view for create and update of Contents. I'm using a class based view inherit from "View" for both create and update views so i can't use the TranslatableCreateView and TranslatableUpdateView. I saw in the codes of Django parler that using TranslatableModelFormMixin you can add translation support to the class-based views. I used this mixin but still i don't have access to the language tabs.

Here is Views.py:

```
class ContentCreateUpdateView(TranslatableModelFormMixin, TemplateResponseMixin, View):
module = None
model = None
obj = None
template_name = 'content-form.html'

def get_model(self, model_name):
    if model_name in ['text', 'video', 'image', 'file']:
        return apps.get_model(app_label='courses', model_name=model_name)
    return None

def get_form(self, model, *args, **kwargs):
    Form = modelform_factory(model, exclude=['owner',
                                             'order',
                                             'created',
                                             'updated'])
    return Form(*args, **kwargs)

def dispatch(self, request, module_id, model_name, id=None):
    self.module = get_object_or_404(Module, id=module_id, course__owner=request.user)
    self.model = self.get_model(model_name)
    if id:
        self.obj = get_object_or_404(self.model,
                                     id=id,
                                     owner=request.user)
    return super().dispatch(request, module_id, model_name, id)

def get(self, request, module_id, model_name, id=None):
    form = self.get_form(self.model, instance=self.obj,)
    return self.render_to_response({'form': form, 'object': self.obj})

def post(self, request, module_id, model_name, id=None):
    form = self.get_form(self.model, instance=self.obj, data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.owner = request.user
        obj.save()
        if not id:
            # new content
            Content.objects.create(module=self.module, item=obj)
        return redirect('module_content_list', self.module.id)
    return self.render_to_response({'form': form, 'object': self.obj})
```

Template:

```
{% extends '_base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load crispy_forms_filters %}

{% block content %}
<div class="col-md-12">
    <!-- Horizontal Form -->
    <div class="card card-primary">
        <div class="card-header ">
            {% if object %}
                <h3 class="card-title mb-0 float-left"> Edit Content "{{ object.title }}"</h3>
            {% else %}
                <h3 class="card-title mb-0 float-left"> Add New Content</h3>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <!-- /.card-header -->
        <!-- form start -->
        <div class="card-body">
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        {% if language_tabs %}
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                {% for url,name,code,status in language_tabs %}
                                    {% if status == 'current' %}
                                        <input type="hidden" class="language_button selected" name="{{ code }}"/>
                                        <li class="nav-item">
                                            <a class="current nav-link active"
                                               aria-selected="true">{{ name }}</a>
                                        </li>
                                    {% else %}
                                        <li class="nav-item">
                                            <a class="{{ status }} nav-link"
                                               href="{{ url }}"
                                               aria-selected="false">{{ name }}</a>
                                        </li>
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-6">
                        
                        {{ form }}

                    </div>
                </div>
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="col-6">
                    <button class="btn btn-success">Save Content</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.card -->
```

{% endblock %}

Here is the source code of django parler:

```
class TranslatableModelFormMixin(LanguageChoiceMixin):
"""
Mixin to add translation support to class based views.

For example, adding translation support to django-oscar::

    from oscar.apps.dashboard.catalogue import views as oscar_views
    from parler.views import TranslatableModelFormMixin

    class ProductCreateUpdateView(TranslatableModelFormMixin, oscar_views.ProductCreateUpdateView):
        pass
"""

def get_form_class(self):
    """
    Return a ``TranslatableModelForm`` by default if no form_class is set.
    """
    super_method = super().get_form_class
    # no "__func__" on the class level function in python 3
    default_method = getattr(
        ModelFormMixin.get_form_class, "__func__", ModelFormMixin.get_form_class
    )
    if not (super_method.__func__ is default_method):
        # Don't get in your way, if you've overwritten stuff.
        return super_method()
    else:
        # Same logic as ModelFormMixin.get_form_class, but using the right form base class.
        if self.form_class:
            return self.form_class
        else:
            model = _get_view_model(self)
            if self.fields:
                fields = self.fields
                return modelform_factory(model, form=TranslatableModelForm, fields=fields)
            else:
                return modelform_factory(model, form=TranslatableModelForm)

def get_form_kwargs(self):
    """
    Pass the current language to the form.
    """
    kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    # The TranslatableAdmin can set form.language_code, because the modeladmin always creates a fresh subclass.
    # If that would be done here, the original globally defined form class would be updated.
    kwargs["_current_language"] = self.get_form_language()
    return kwargs

# Backwards compatibility
# Make sure overriding get_current_language() affects get_form_language() too.
def get_form_language(self):
    return self.get_current_language()
```

The tabs should look like this:
[image: Translations tabs]

But now it looks like this:

[image: There is no Translation tabs]

If someone have a similiar exprience, feel free to write your opinion

Answer (score 1):

In the settings.py file find PARLER_LANGUAGES settings and change None to SITE_ID.

```
PARLER_LANGUAGES = {
    1: (
        {'code': 'en', },  # English
        {'code': 'ru', },  # Russian
    ),
    'default': {
        'fallbacks': ['en'],
        'hide_untranslated': False,
    }
}
```